# How to get data from BackEnd in a RESTful architecture?

Tags: javascript, java, rest, post

I'm building a RESTful architecture using a `Java` Backend and an `Angular` Frontend. The idea is the following: given a form with a bunch of `Fields`, the Frontend generates a `JSON` file and sends it to the Backend, where it will be processed with `xdocreport` along with a `.docx` template file in order to perform a context replacement. This pipeline generates a `.docx` file that I should somehow return to the Frontend, either downloading it or by returning a `Response` containing a `byte[]` entity.

So, this is my post in the Backend:

```
@POST
@Path("/form/{category}/export")
public Response generateDoc(JSONObject jObj) {
    Response.ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok(Controller.generateDocument(
                                                Utils.getFileExtension(jObj.get("metadata").toString()),
                                                (ArrayList)jObj.get("data"),
                                                jObj.get("metadata").toString()
                                                ));
    rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS");
    rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
    return rb.build();
}
```

where `Controller.generateDocument()` is a static method that actually generates the document and returns a `byte[]`.
My request in the Frontend is:

```
exportToBackend(): void {
    this.fields.forEach(field=>{
      field.value = this.formGroup.value[field.label];
      if (field.label == 'image') {
        field.value = this.imgURL;
      }
    });

    let result = {metadata: this.selectedTemplate, data: this.fields};

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With'
      })
    };
    this.http.post<Uint8Array>('http://localhost:8080/ExportLibrary-BackEnd-1.0-SNAPSHOT/form/'
      .concat(this.category).concat('/export'), result, httpOptions).toPromise().then(data => {
        this.doc = data;
    });

 }
```

When I run it, the document is generated correctly (I create both the byte[] object and the actual `.docx` file as a sort of "debugging") but in the Frontend I get a `Uint8Array (0)` empty object, and I can't understand why. Moreover, from that array I should also create the `.docx` file. More precisely, the error I get is the following:

[image: HttpResponseError]

even if I don't use `JSON` files **at all** in the Backend.

So, my questions are: where am I wrong? How can I get the actual data from the Java `Response` object in the Frontend?

Finally, I've seen a bunch of examples (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278535/angular-6-download-file-after-getting-file-object-from-backend-server)) that actually download the file from the Backend. How does that work? Is it a better way than getting the `byte[]` object?

Comment: In your backend class, you are not setting response header with file info and proper content type (MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
Can you take a look at below implementation for your response? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680932/download-a-file-from-spring-boot-rest-service

Comment: @Vasif thanks for answering! Thing is, I can't use `.contentType()` since the `ResponseBuilder` doesn't find the method reference. Moreover, if I try to adapt my code to the answer you linked, my lib can't even find the `ResponseEntity` object.

Comment: what if instead builder you can use ResponseEntity in your method and generate it as 

ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(generateDocument(......));
ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .contentLength(file.length())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .body(resource);

Comment: @Vasif I tried, but I have no `ResponseEntity` in my library. Maybe it has been deprecated in an older version and it's no more available.

Comment: I thought you are using spring-boot but probably you are using simple jax-ws. So, anyway you can add header like rb.header("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

Comment: Yes, my bad, I forgot to specify, sorry! Anyway, I've tried to add the header, but I still get the same `HttpResponseError`.